# add custom attribute to RadDatePicker

Tags: asp.net, telerik, raddatepicker, telerik-datepicker

I'm trying to add a custom attribute on a `RadDatePicker` but it adds the attribute to the wrapper instead of the inputfield.
is there a way to add an attribute to the input field of a `RadDatePicker`

I found that if I opened the controls and selected the first value in my watch, I'd get the input field + it had an `attributes` attribute.
but when trying to add an attribute to the first Control, it gives a red squigly line saying that `rdp.Controls[0].Attributes` doesn't exist.

my code:

```
RadDatePicker rdp = (RadDatePicker)control_object[control_id];
rdp.Attributes.Add("controlID", control_id);

rdp.Controls[0].Attributes.Add("controlID", control_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

I had to define the rdp.Controls[0] as a radDateInput.

```
//1 liner
((RadDateInput)rdp.Controls[0]).Attributes.Add("controlID", control_id);

//2 lines
RadDateInput rdi = (RadDateInput)rdp.Controls[0];
rdi.Attributes.Add("controlID", control_id);
```

Comment: If this has solved your problem, then you can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I had to wait 2 days and then I forgot :)